# Merging 2 arrays with different value types

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongoose

Developing in MEAN stack. Express received and process req array parameters (initially string) and Mongoose returns object array property. I am facing very strange problem. Console.log outputs arrays as follows:

```
var arr1 = [ '5acde7adf7d2520e3b205970', '5acde7c0f7d2520e3b205971' ];
var arr2 = ["5acde7adf7d2520e3b205970","5acde7c0f7d2520e3b205971"];
```

first array is a JSON.parsed variable, second the property of MangoDB returned array property.

I need to compare arrays and if they different - perform operation.

Lodash isEqual function is always false.
Lodash union the same as concat and filter, output arrays as follows  (log output):

```
[ 5acde7adf7d2520e3b205970,
  5acde7c0f7d2520e3b205971,
  '5acde7adf7d2520e3b205970',
  '5acde7c0f7d2520e3b205971' ]
```

If I check types of each array value then the first array values are objects the second are strings...

The only way I can property merge arrays is by preprocessing them like: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr1)). Then all values are strings and merged properly as they shall:

```
[ '5acde7adf7d2520e3b205970', '5acde7c0f7d2520e3b205971' ]
```

Anybody faced this problem? Probably have some better ideas how to handle it

The best solution I found, for my problem, is to use map function to even array values. Ex:

```
arr2.map(String)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's always going to be an array of primitives, it should be quite easy to just compare each of their values like so:

```js
const arr1 = [ '5acde7adf7d2520e3b205970', '5acde7c0f7d2520e3b205971' ];
const arr2 = ["5acde7adf7d2520e3b205970","5acde7c0f7d2520e3b205971"];
const isSame = (arr1, arr2) => {
  if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) return false;
  return arr1.every((arr1elm, i) => arr1elm === arr2[i]);
}
console.log(isSame(arr1, arr2));
```

The fact that one array may have been defined with double quotes and one with single quotes shouldn't affect anything, since they're already deserialized - it's still an array of strings underneath, not a string itself.

Comment: That's what I am saying. If I compare valued individually - its fine. But I need to work with arrays in my case (exclude, merge, etc) so I need to even their types prior. Ain't I? Although it returns false... Hmmm

Comment: If your values aren't actually strings but are arrays themselves too, then just use `isSame` on the inner arrays too - use it recursively. There are lots of posts here about efficient ways to determine object equality.

Comment: The best solution I've found is to use '**.map(String)** on the second array (array of objects). Thanks a lot you for your prompt answer.