# Map and Filter to populate array with objects by id

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to populate array of ids with objects. In other words I have. Array of ids:

```
var orderArray = ["5ace454a2b22e17597d0e694", "5acde7c0f7d2520e3b205971", "5ad2086bf05ad342dc723ea1"]
```

And array of objects:

```
var objectsArray = [ { _id: 5acde7c0f7d2520e3b205971,
    name: 'Dinner',
    restaurant: 5a68d8ea17d9e4308e6400c3,
    created: 2018-04-11T10:47:28.957Z,
    status: true,
    products: [ [Object] ] },
  { _id: 5ace454a2b22e17597d0e694,
    name: 'Test',
    restaurant: 5a68d8ea17d9e4308e6400c3,
    image: 
     { _id: 5ad23ed177bcd07303f62899,
       filename: 'rJKCR2k2f-1523728081111.jpeg',
       destination: 'images',
       binded: true },
    created: 2018-04-11T17:26:34.186Z,
    status: false,
    products: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { _id: 5ad2086bf05ad342dc723ea1,
    name: 'Test',
    restaurant: 5a68d8ea17d9e4308e6400c3,
    image: null,
    created: 2018-04-14T13:55:55.449Z,
    status: true,
    products: [] } ]
```

Either you can sort array of objects based on ids... Or map array of ids to array of objects. Probably I'd prefer the second option.
But my approach just doesn't work

```
orderArray.map(id => objectsArray.filter(obj => obj._id == id))
```

*The result shall be*: objectsArray is sorted as order of elements in orderArray

**SOLUTION:** I've opened this question few days ago: [Merging 2 arrays with different value types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49779348/merging-2-arrays-with-different-value-types/4977942)

Here I have the same problem. orderArray is array of objects (not string) thus in order to make it work I need to apply the solution I found earlier (both Array.filter and Array.find functions works well):
but in my way it will work only if:

```
order_array.map(String).map(e => objectsArray.find(a => a._id == e))
//as well as 
order_array.map(String).map(e => objectsArray.filter(a => a._id == e))
```

Comment: what exactly are you looking for as to output?

Comment: Use `find` instead of `filter`, otherwise you get an extra nested array.

Comment: @tricot no both works fine.. The problem here lies beyond... See the solution and referenced post

Comment: @tricot although if you know the answer to the referenced post - I'd love to hear it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map` the first array to fill it with corresponding elements from the second one :

```js
var orderArray = ["5ace454a2b22e17597d0e694", "5acde7c0f7d2520e3b205971", "5ad2086bf05ad342dc723ea1"]

var objectsArray = [ { _id: '5acde7c0f7d2520e3b205971',
    name: 'Dinner',
    restaurant: '5a68d8ea17d9e4308e6400c3',
    created: '2018-04-11T10:47:28.957Z',
    status: true,
    products: [ [Object] ] },
  { _id: '5ace454a2b22e17597d0e694',
    name: 'Test',
    restaurant: '5a68d8ea17d9e4308e6400c3',
    image: 
     { _id: '5ad23ed177bcd07303f62899',
       filename: 'rJKCR2k2f-1523728081111.jpeg',
       destination: 'images',
       binded: true },
    created: '2018-04-11T17:26:34.186Z',
    status: false,
    products: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { _id: '5ad2086bf05ad342dc723ea1',
    name: 'Test',
    restaurant: '5a68d8ea17d9e4308e6400c3',
    image: null,
    created: '2018-04-14T13:55:55.449Z',
    status: true,
    products: [] } ]
    
 var sorted = orderArray.map((e) => { return objectsArray.find((a) => { return a._id  == e})})
 
 console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: Thank you @Taki. I've done it as well. but I am having following output... [ undefined, undefined, undefined ]. Does NodeJS support ES6?

Comment: Looks like I done its my fault. Checked and it works.. Probably some typo.. Thanks

Comment: these are the verions of nodejs that supports ES6 https://node.green/ , and check your JSON, i edited it to be valid in my snippet ( adding quotes )

Comment: Found the problem. If interested - see the post

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to:

```
objectsArray.filter(obj => ordersArray.includes(obj._id));
```

If I am understanding correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Using `map`/`find` (instead of `filter`):

```
let mappedArray = orderArray.map(id => objectsArray.find(obj => obj._id == id));
```

which `map`s `orderArray` to an array of objects, where it `find`s the object from `objectsArray` that has the same `_id` as the current `id`.

**Note:** If there is no object in `objectsArray` that matches the `id`, `null` will be returned.